# How to Make PHP Fail Gracefully if getColumnMeta Not Supported by Driver

Tags: php, pdo

Sample of code:

```
$dbcon = new PDO(blah blah blah);
$getmeta = $dbcon->query("Select * from my_tble");
$i = 0;
while ($column = $getmeta->getColumnMeta($i++)) 
{
    print_r($column);
}
```

I fully understand that getColumnMeta only works for some drivers. My app allows use with multiple drivers. I am trying to solve for how to determine if the driver supports getColumnMeta and/or how to fail gracefully if it does not support the function.

Currently, even in a try/catch block the app fails with:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getColumnMeta() on bool

Thus, my question is, how can I programmatically determine if the driver being used supports getColumnMeta and/or how can I avoid the call if the driver does not support the function?

Thanks for any input or ideas!

Comment: [`method_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)?

Comment: @El_Vanja - thanks. I had tried that a few different ways. Maybe I am using the test incorrectly?  if (method_exists($dbcon,getColumnMeta())) - I literally get an error "Call to undefined function getColumnMeta()" which was connfusing, being that is for what I was testing.

Comment: You only need to supply the *name* of the function. By adding parentheses, you're trying to execute a function. So just `method_exists($dbcon, 'getColumnMeta')`.

Comment: Holy Cow - that was my inability to read documentation. I completely, completely overlooked that the function name needed to be in quotes. Even when you wrote it above, at first I knew I already tried that. ...then I finally noticed the single ticks.  dunno how I overlooked the tickmarks in the PHP docs and in your comment initially.  Thank you for your follow-up!